# MySQL using ridiculous amount of memory to import 1-2GB SQL files

Tags: mysql, docker, memory, sql, mysqldump

I have a MySQL server running on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine via Docker. The machine has 32 GB of RAM.

I have about 300 1-2GB SQL files which need importing into a database on the server, into a single table.

The database itself is completely empty, and there is only one table in total.

When I try to import some of the files, I can see memory usage spike to 32 GB (100%), and after allocating 100 GB of swap memory, the highest I've seen it go to is 60 GB **(60 GB + 32 GB = 92 GB!!!)**

Bearing in mind that MySQL is trying to use 92 GB of RAM to import a 1 GB SQL file into a single table on an empty database, what could it possibly be doing? It does not seem to be a memory leak, because once the file is finished importing, the memory becomes unallocated.

I should probably mention that MySQL is using a Docker volume which the host has direct file access to to store its data.

I have tried many different configurations to fix this problem, and additionally, I sometimes will get a `MySQL server has gone away` error.

I have tried the following:

- Changing the table from InnoDB to MyISAM and running `ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS`
- Setting `autocommit=0`, `unique_checks=0`, `foreign_key_checks=0`
- Setting `max_allowed_packet=999999999G` and the relevant timeout variables to similar values
- Using [mysqltuner.pl](https://mysqltuner.com) to generate some optimal InnoDB config options (shown below)

The SQL files themselves are literally a single INSERT statement with thousands of rows.

What can I do? I have considered chunking the INSERT statement into multiple different INSERTs, but this would require some extensive code refactoring due to the multiprocessing flow of my program which generates the SQL files.

**my.cnf**:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 9999999G
wait_timeout = 99999999999
key_buffer_size=10M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=21G
innodb_log_file_size=2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=21
innodb_file_per_table
net_read_timeout=999999999999
net_write_timeout=999999999999

pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= NULL
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Custom config should go here
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

The problem consistently persisted even after adding and fiddling with the `innodb_*` variables.

**show global variables**:

https://pastebin.com/raw/pXK4MgFb

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

No amount of RAM or disk space in the civilized world could hold what `max_allowed_packet = 9999999G` wants to allocate!  Put that back to the default, or at most `256M`.

> The SQL files themselves are literally a single INSERT statement with thousands of rows.

This is optimal.

So, the total table size is somewhere around half a terabyte?  The time taken to write that much disk is in the hours, depending on type of disk.

Not *not* use swap space; that only slows down MySQL.  A lot.  However, your settings do not seem to actually use the swap space.  21G for the buffer_pool should keep RAM usage well under the 32G physical size.  However, you say it spiked to 100%?  I guess I am missing something.  If there is any swapping, MySQL will slow down, so lower the buffer_pool_size a little to avoid swapping.

`autocommit=0` with InnoDB is not efficient -- If there is no `COMMIT`, then the data is inserted, then rolled back.  If there is a `COMMIT`, then it has to do a lot of work to prepare for a rollback.  Set to `ON`.

Is it disabling and re-enabling "keys" 300 times?  That means that the indexes are rebuilt 300 times.  Did the files run slower and slower as you went through through the 300?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try setting `max_allowed_packet` back to a normal value when I am back in the office - I didn't know it had anything to do with memory allocation, just wanted to fix `MySQL server has gone away`. I'm not sure where you got that table size figure from, but the SQL files are approximately a total of 300 GB in size. And all of the troubleshooting stuff I did was just purely troubleshooting, none of it fixed the issue anyway. Regarding the swap memory, I am not intending for MySQL to use it, I just allocated it so that it doesn't run out of memory and crash.

Comment: @Billy - The size of the dump file is approximately the size of the table(s) that it can create.  (This estimate can be off by a factor of 2, possibly more.)  Swap:  Good; have it just in case, but avoid using it.

Comment: @RickJames Good answer :-) I think you wrote a small typo: "Not not use swap space". Don't you mean "Do not use swap space" instead?

Comment: @RickJames So I have modified max_allowed_packet to be 256M, and the memory issue doesn't even get a chance to appear because I just get "MySQL server has gone away." Increasing it brings back the memory issue but mitigates that error message.

Comment: I solved the issue by splitting the INSERTs into groups of 500 rows. Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: @Billy - Perhaps `max_allowed_packet` was either too small for each insert batch or too big for RAM.  Glad you got the problem fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was! The maximum isn't enough for such a big INSERT, and the big INSERT itself was too big for the RAM! Would've assumed that MySQL would deal with that kind of stuff appropriately but I guess not.

Comment: @Billy The max (upper) limit for max_allowed_packet is 1G. Cold, hard fact.  Check your reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I would say:

- during the import set:

  - `max_allowed_packet=10G` (to make memory available for the `INSERT`)
  - `innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G` (or less) to free up server memory, you can increase this later when you are using the server for queries, but for inserts it's almost useless
  - `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0` for better I/O performance (definitely remove or set to 1 or 2 for production use!)

Also, there is a problem with `INSERT` statements that are too big for one transaction. Basically, if your transaction is too big for the redo log, it will fail. Definitely set `AUTOCOMMIT=1`, remove any `START TRANSACTION` lines from your dump files and if this doesn't help, increase the log file size: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1265/12685

---

In addition I realized you are generating those SQL files programmatically. It will be more efficient to fire those inserts one by one to the database server, especially with the settings above, and it will be fast if you use `INSERT DELAYED`.

Comment: Please correct your advice on max_allowed_packet.  The max (upper) limit is 1G.

Comment: `INSERT DELAYED` is going away; don't recommend it. -- https://mysqlserverteam.com/removal-and-deprecation-in-mysql-5-7/ .  Anyway, I think it is a no-op on InnoDB.